# Nested xtab tables

Tags: r

I would like to produce nested tables for a multilevel factorial experiment. I have 10 paints examined for time to reach an end point under 4 levels of humidity, 3 temperatures and 2 wind speeds. Of course I have searched on line but without success.

Some sample code can be generated using:

```
##  Made  Up  Data  # NB the data is continuous whereas observations were made 40/168 so data is censored.
 time3 <- 4*seq(1:24)   # Dependent: times in hrs, runif is not really representative but will do
 wind  <- c(1,2)        # Independent: factor draught on or off
 RH    <- c(0,35,75,95) # Independent: value for RH but can be processes as a factor
 temp  <- c(5,11,20)    # Independent: value for temperature but can be processed as a factor
 paint <- c("paintA", "paintB", "paintC")   # Independent: Experimental material
# Combine into dataframe 
 dfa       <- data.frame(rep(temp,8))
 dfa$RH    <- rep(RH,6)
 dfa$wind  <- rep(wind,12)
 dfa$time3 <- time3
 dfa$paint <- rep(paint[1],24)
# Replicate for different paints
 dfb       <-  dfa
 dfb$paint <-  paint[2]  
 dfc       <-  dfa
 dfc$paint <-  paint[3]
 dfx       <-  do.call("rbind", list(dfa,dfb,dfc))
# Rename first col 
 colnames(dfx)[1] <- "temp" 
# Prepare xtab tables
 tx <- xtabs(dfx$time3 ~ dfx$wind + dfx$RH + dfx$temp + dfx$paint)
 tx
```

And the target I hope to obtain would be like this [xtab example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W0q7Ay34ceMzMfVpkP28v8hlWf6ucf5dxlMS4lsCzbg/edit?usp=drivesdk)

This 
`tx <- xtabs(dfx$time3 ~ dfx$wind + dfx$RH + dfx$temp)`
does not work well enough. I would also like to write to C:\file.csv for printing and reporting etc. Please advise on how to achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can `paste` the two variables you want to nest together. Since the items will be ordered lexicographically, you will need to zero-pad the temp variable, to get numerical ordering.

```
xtabs(time3~wind+paste(sprintf("%02d",temp),RH,sep=":")+paint,dfx)
, , paint = paintA

    paste(sprintf("%02d", temp), RH, sep = ":")
wind 05:0 05:35 05:75 05:95 11:0 11:35 11:75 11:95 20:0 20:35 20:75 20:95
   1   56     0   104     0   88     0   136     0  120     0    72     0
   2    0   128     0    80    0    64     0   112    0    96     0   144

, , paint = paintB

    paste(sprintf("%02d", temp), RH, sep = ":")
wind 05:0 05:35 05:75 05:95 11:0 11:35 11:75 11:95 20:0 20:35 20:75 20:95
   1   56     0   104     0   88     0   136     0  120     0    72     0
   2    0   128     0    80    0    64     0   112    0    96     0   144

, , paint = paintC

    paste(sprintf("%02d", temp), RH, sep = ":")
wind 05:0 05:35 05:75 05:95 11:0 11:35 11:75 11:95 20:0 20:35 20:75 20:95
   1   56     0   104     0   88     0   136     0  120     0    72     0
   2    0   128     0    80    0    64     0   112    0    96     0   144
```